# How to use multiple case statements in Scala?

Tags: scala

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(dateExtract("2020-05-15","yyyy-MM-dd","moo"))             
   }   
  def dateExtract(date: String, ipFormat: String, field: String): String ={
      var dateformat  = ipFormat;
      val dtf = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateformat)
      val dateString = date;
      val d = java.time.LocalDate.parse(dateString, dtf)
      var yea1="";
      var mon1="";
      field match {
    case years =>  val yea = d.getYear
                    yea1=yea.toString
    case moo => val mth = d.getMonth
                    mon1=mth.toString    
  }
      mon1
    }
```

In this code I have passed 3 arguments to the function dateExtract .
In the function dateExtract  I used the third argument for case statement,
but it shows warnings like this

```
`Solution.scala:20: warning: patterns after a variable pattern cannot match (SLS 8.1.1)
    case years =>  val yea = d.getYear
         ^
Solution.scala:22: warning: unreachable code due to variable pattern 'years' on line 20
    case moo => val mth = d.getMonth
             ^
Solution.scala:22: warning: unreachable code
    case moo => val mth = d.getMonth
             ^
three warnings found`
```

Give me a solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to match `Strings` `"years"` and `"moo"` and then return `Year` or `Month` value based on the function parameter passed. If that's the case then in your pattern matching you are not matching `String` value, you are matching some variable `year` which is showing the warning. Also please don't use `var` try to use `val`. Try the below code,

```
def dateExtract(date: String, ipFormat: String, field: String): String = {
    val dtf = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ipFormat)
    val d = java.time.LocalDate.parse(date, dtf)
    field match {
      case "years" => d.getYear.toString
      case "moo" => d.getMonth.toString
      //uncomment it if you want to include default case
      //case _ => what you want to do in case your String doesn't matches any of the above cases.
    }
}
```